# Does Tregelles' description of the Armenian edition imply that Greek manuscripts were routinely altered to match the Vulgate?

Tags: textual-criticism

Does Tregelles' description of the Armenian edition imply that translations based on Greek manuscripts were routinely altered to match the Vulgate?

> **The Armenian Version by Miesrob in the fourth century: the edition of Zohrab, taken from MSS., and devoid of alteration from the Latin** (Venice, 1805), has been used through the kind and efficient assistance of Dr. Charles Rieu. (Arm. Usc. refers to the edition of Uscan; Arm. Zoh. to that of Zohrab; Arm. m. to codices multi.)

> Tregelles, S. P. (Ed.). (1857–1879). The Greek New Testament: Apparatus. London: Samuel Bagster and Sons; C. J. Stewart.

While the description is cryptic, it appears to be a Greek text as the entries refer to the Greek. For example, this is a note on an omission from Revelation 20:10 showing 5 omitted Greek words:

— εις τους αιων. τ. αιων. Er. Cmpl. | om. 1. Arm.

Tregelles, S. P. (Ed.). (1857–1879). The Greek New Testament: Apparatus (p. 1008). London: Samuel Bagster and Sons; C. J. Stewart.

In addition, the "1" that precedes "Arm." in the Revelation 20:10 example I provide above is, according to Logos software, indicating: [Codex Basilensis.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codex_Basilensis)

Comment: Is the Zohrab edition Greek or Armenian? Maybe he means that the Armenian text didn't have differences from the Latin? (Even though it surely would, as all translations have differences...)

Comment: It appears to be a Greek text as the entries refer to the Greek. For example, this is a note on an omission from Revelation 20:10 showing five omitted Greek words:   


  — εις τους αιων. τ. αιων. Er. Cmpl. | om. 1. Arm.


Tregelles, S. P. (Ed.). (1857–1879). The Greek New Testament: Apparatus (p. 1008). London: Samuel Bagster and Sons; C. J. Stewart.  However, regardless, the question is still valid.

Comment: [Miesrob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesrop_Mashtots) and [Zohrab](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1326866702) are Armenian bible versions; apparently, the former relied more strongly on Latin manuscripts than the latter.

Comment: Thanks for the links. It is a cryptic description. It sounds like he's saying it was created in the fourth century in Greek and then published in the 1800s without modifying it to match the Vulgate, doesn't it? Tregelles seems to have prepared the apparatus in 1879. It's confusing to me.

Comment: What does the amrenian version and zohrab edition even mean? The Q should clarify. Is it Armenian languages?

Comment: @Ruminator: No, it doesn't, to be quite honest; sounds perfectly clear even to my non-English ears, in fact.

Comment: @Lucian  Well, I've resolved it. It is from the Greek of the fourth century. Please see what I added to the question.

Comment: And what does Basel have to do with either of the two Armenian ones ?

Comment: The codices are stored at that school.